# React form validation hook causes infinite re-render loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint

**I've checked for other questions, they didn't help me**

I built a React hook to validate my form inputs. However, it causes an infinite re-render loop. I've tracked down the problem to the `useEffect` dependency array. When I exclude the `validators` dependency, it works great! I won't ever change the `validators` during runtime, so is this prop is not needed in the dependency array? My `ESLint` `react-hooks-plugin` keeps giving me a warning that the `validators` dependency is missing. Please help me out. Can I leave out the `validators` dependency from the `useEffect` dependency array if I won't change it during runtime? Here is my hook and my form component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function setObjectValues<
  K extends { [key: string]: unknown },
  T
>(
  object: K,
  value: T
): { [key in keyof K]?: T } {
  const initialResults: {
    [key in keyof K]?: T;
  } = {};
  for (const key in object) {
    initialResults[key] = value;
  }
  return initialResults;
}

export function useValidation<
  K,
  T extends {
    [key: string]: (value: K) => boolean;
  }
>(
  value: K,
  validators: T
): {
  valid: boolean;
  results: { [key in keyof T]?: boolean };
} {
  const [results, setResults] = useState<
    { [key in keyof T]?: boolean }
  >(setObjectValues(validators, true));

  useEffect(() => {
    const newResults: {
      [key in keyof T]?: boolean;
    } = {};

    for (const key in validators) {
      const valid = validators[key](value);
      newResults[key] = valid;
    }

    setResults(newResults);
  }, [value, validators]);

  const valid = Object.values(results).every(
    (item) => item === true
  );

  return { valid, results };
}
```

My component:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import {
  useFirebase,
  useValidation,
} from "app/hooks";
import {
  useState,
  useCallback,
  FormEvent,
} from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

type InputType = "email" | "password";

const SignUp: NextPage = () => {
  const firebase = useFirebase();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const {
    valid: emailValid,
    results: emailValidationResults,
  } = useValidation(email, {
    containsAt: (value) => value.includes("@"),
  });

  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const {
    valid: passwordValid,
    results: passwordValidationResults,
  } = useValidation(password, {
    isLongEnough: (value) => value.length >= 8,
    containsLowerCase: (value) =>
      value.toUpperCase() !== value,
    containsUpperCase: (value) =>
      value.toLowerCase() !== value,
    containsNumber: (value) => /\d/.test(value),
  });

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (
        emailValid === true &&
        passwordValid === true &&
        email !== "" &&
        password !== ""
      ) {
        const error = firebase.createUser(
          email,
          password
        );
        if (error) {
          console.warn(error.code);
        } else {
          router.push("/");
        }
      } else {
        console.warn("Invalid user values");
      }
    },
    [
      email,
      emailValid,
      firebase,
      password,
      passwordValid,
      router,
    ]
  );

  console.log(emailValid, passwordValid);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input
        value={email}
        onChange={(event): void =>
          setEmail(event.target.value)
        }
        id="email"
        placeholder="Email"
      />
      <p>{emailValid}</p>
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input
        value={password}
        onChange={(event): void =>
          setPassword(event.target.value)
        }
        id="password"
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <p>{passwordValid}</p>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const {
    valid: passwordValid,
    results: passwordValidationResults,
  } = useValidation(password, {
    isLongEnough: (value) => value.length >= 8,
    containsLowerCase: (value) =>
      value.toUpperCase() !== value,
    containsUpperCase: (value) =>
      value.toLowerCase() !== value,
    containsNumber: (value) => /\d/.test(value),
  });
```

Here, `validators` is actually an Object that is created during `Signup` render. When you create a new Object, it is always a new, different object, even though the values inside of it might be the same. This is the reason why adding it to the dependencies array causes infinite re-renders.

If the object does not depend on your component's state or props, move the declaration to outside of the component so that it is only created once.

```
// outside SignUp
const validators = {
    isLongEnough: (value) => value.length >= 8,
    containsLowerCase: (value) =>
      value.toUpperCase() !== value,
    containsUpperCase: (value) =>
      value.toLowerCase() !== value,
    containsNumber: (value) => /\d/.test(value),
  };

// inside SignUp
const {
    valid: passwordValid,
    results: passwordValidationResults,
  } = useValidation(password, validators);
```

I would suggest keeping `validators` in the dependencies array, because it should still work anyway. Leaving it out most of the time is a code smell. Most of the time, if `validators` changed, you will want the effect to be re-run again.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! This fixed my problem. I find that so often the troubles around object and their equality causes so many issues in JS. I have one more question: would you recommend leaving the `valid` property inside the function like it is or should I move it into a `useState` hook? I feel like it could work great as derived state, by putting it inside a `useEffect`, but then I'm unsure about how to return a value after calculating it inside `useEffect` because I would have to set a state from the `useEffect`, it's then no longer derived state.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, basically, you want to compute a value based on the value `valid`. and use that computed value instead? Although there are cases where you might want to compute the value in `useEffect`, in most cases computing the value inside the render function is good enough. If you put it in `useEffect`, you would have to trigger a `setState` to update the UI again. I would recommend reading [this excellent article](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/#principle-1-dont-stop-the-data-flow) from Dan Abramov to get yourself more comfortable with React